# notifyListeners() of nested Provider is not updating the UI

Tags: flutter

I'm using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) Flutter package.

I have a main list and each item of the main list has a sublist. I can add items to the main list and it's working but every time I add something to the sublist the UI is not getting updated. Run the code and add some items and open them then add some items there (this is the sublist) and you will see you won't see any update but if you minimize the keyboard the UI will get updated. Maybe because I am using `Provider.of<Collection>(context)`to access the object of the sublist and `notifyListeners()` of the `CityName` class can't run the `findById(id)` this is what I can think of.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Collection(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: CityName(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                  children: Provider.of<Collection>(context)
                      .cityNameCollection
                      .map((collection) {
                return CollectionCard(collection.title, collection.id);
              }).toList()),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _textEditingController,
                      autofocus: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Provider.of<Collection>(context)
                          .addCollection(_textEditingController.text);
                      _textEditingController.clear();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'ADD',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class CollectionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String id;

  CollectionCard(this.title, this.id);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20),
          child: Text(title),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CityNamesList(id),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CityNamesList extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  CityNamesList(this.id);
  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final item = Provider.of<Collection>(context).findById(id);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(item.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
                children: item.names.map((name) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(name),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  onPressed: () {
                    item.removeName(name);
                  },
                ),
              );
            }).toList()),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textEditingController,
                    autofocus: true,
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    item.addName(_textEditingController.text);
                    _textEditingController.clear();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'ADD',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Collection with ChangeNotifier {
  List<CityName> cityNameCollection = [];

  void addCollection(value) {
    cityNameCollection
        .add(CityName(title: value, id: DateTime.now().toString()));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  CityName findById(id) {
    return cityNameCollection.firstWhere((a) => a.id == id);
  }
}

class CityName with ChangeNotifier {
  String title;
  String id;
  List<String> names = [];

  CityName({this.title, this.id});

  void addName(value) {
    names.add(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeName(value) {
    names.remove(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example seems too complex. Please reduce it to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: actually this is a dummy version of the main app. The simplified version of the main app. The main structure is there a main list and each item has another list.  I can't simplify more or there won't be any issue in the first place. When I make nested list I see this problem.

Comment: Well, I figured it out somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems here

1) You are creating `Collection()` inside `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` which can lead to recreating it (not just now but after some changes in code). Instead use `ChangeNotifierProvider` with `builder` which will create the value exactly once

2) You are using **single** `ChangeNotifierProvider` for `CityName` while there can be multiple `CityName` instances. So instead of referring to specific instance of `CityName` all providers will always give you the same one

3) Passing `collection.id` and then finding it by id is not necessary and complicates the code. Just pass the collection instance itself

4) `CityNamesList` dosen't get provided specific `CityName` but gets it from `Collection` provider. In this case the UI will not be rebuilt because it does not listen to `CityNamesList` changes. Actually it listens to `Collection` changes but `Collection` *doesn't know* when its item changes because no one calls `notifyListeners()` **on `Collection`** inside `CityName@addName`

5) Finally, `CityName`'s constructor fields are optional (not required) which allows to create dummy instances and leads to errors

Here is an example how you can fix this problems (without `removeName` for simplicity)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => Collection(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: Provider.of<Collection>(context)
                  .cityNameCollection
                  .map((item) => CollectionCard(item))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _textEditingController,
                  autofocus: true,
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Provider.of<Collection>(context)
                      .addCollection(_textEditingController.text);
                  _textEditingController.clear();
                },
                child: Text('ADD'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CollectionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final CityName item;

  CollectionCard(this.item);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
          child: Text(item.title),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                value: item,
                child: CityNamesList(),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CityNamesList extends StatelessWidget {
  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final item = Provider.of<CityName>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(item.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: item.names.map((name) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(name),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textEditingController,
                    autofocus: true,
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    item.addName(_textEditingController.text);
                    _textEditingController.clear();
                  },
                  child: Text('ADD'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Collection with ChangeNotifier {
  List<CityName> cityNameCollection = [];

  void addCollection(String value) {
    cityNameCollection.add(CityName(title: value));
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class CityName with ChangeNotifier {
  String title;
  List<String> names = [];

  CityName({@required this.title});

  void addName(value) {
    names.add(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere you must use `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` instead of `builder` when there is a long list. If you scroll up and down the list and you'll get an error. Do you know anything about that? The solution you gave actually I was trying to do exactly that way but I was providing the `CityName()` provider at wrong place I also filed an [issue here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/224) for that. When couldn't fix it I came up with the id solution. And thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I don't think `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` itself can cause an error with long lists

Comment: `I/flutter (27720): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (27720): The following assertion was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
I/flutter (27720): A Product was used after being disposed.
I/flutter (27720): Once you have called dispose() on a Product, it can no longer be used.`

Here that exception. `Product` the provider here. I am not sure if this is a special case. Anyway I will use `builder`.

Comment: I meant `ChangeNotifierProvider` with `builder` in previous comment

Comment: The error isn't caused by long list. It appears when you're using `ChangeNotifierProvider` with `builder` and passing **existing** items to builder. (Then, when Provider is being disposed, it also disposes built item so it can't be used in future). You should only use builder when creating new items together with Provider. To make Provider with an existing item `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` is OK

Answer (score 2):

I had kinda similar issue where UI wouldn't update after I remove an element at a specific index. Had to reconstruct the list using

```
yourList =  List<SomeObj>.from(yourList)..removeAt(idx)

notifyListeners();
```

Comment: Selector relies on the value obtained to be immutable.
yourList = [...yourList , newItem];
This article is helpful to fix issue related with Selector and ChangeNotifierProvider .
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/560

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, where I had multiple providers.

```
 MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Foo()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Bar()),
  ],
  child: const MyApp(),
),
```

I was able to fix by changing `ChangeNotifierProvider` to `ChangeNotifierProvider.value`.

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Foo()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Bar()),
  ],
  child: const MyApp(),
),
```